# Remove UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to remove the indicator from my scroll view (the white horizontal scroll bar). How can I do this?

I currently have this:

```
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```